# Align the inline-block elements

Tags: html, alignment, css

See this fiddle: [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ghpwD/4/)

The last `div` that is the  with `id="3"` is staying at the bottom.What i want to do is bring the `<div id="3">` to the bottom of `<div id="2">`, the right of `<div id="1">`

How can i align that correctly?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing much to be done. Just make your `<div id="1"..>` to `float:left` and remove the display attribute.

```
<div style="float:left;border:1px solid gray;width:48%;word-wrap:break-word;" id="1">
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ghpwD/5/)

Suggestion: `ID's` shouldn't start with a number. Please change your id name's to words.

Comment: It does work because once you float an element they are no longer block elements. So, the display:inline-block has no effect.